# RMI Server, variable value not updated

Tags: java, rmi

This is just a test in order to understand how a java RMI server works. If I execute the server and communicate with an RMI client, the variable "data" should be updated when the getData() method is remotely called by the client. But instead the program keeps printing "hello 2". This means that the variable is not updated, maybe because the server is executed on another process. Can someone clarify this?

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RMIServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RMIi{

    public RMIServer() throws RemoteException{
        super();
    }

    static String data = "Hello";

    @Override
    public String getData(String text) throws RemoteException {
        data = "Hello 4";
        return data;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        while(true) {
            try{
                data = "Hello 2";
                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
                reg.rebind("server", new RMIServer());
                System.out.println("Server Started");
                data = "Hello 3";
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I execute the server and communicate with an RMI client, the variable "data" should be updated when the getData() method is remotely called by the client.

Correct.

> But instead the program keeps printing "hello 2".

What program? There's nothing here that prints that. But `data` is "Hello 2" because of the pointless loop in your `main()`. Remove it.

> This means that the variable is not updated

No it doesn't. It means you keep setting it to that value, inside a pointless loop that also keeps creating new server instances. There's no evidence here that you've executed the client yet.

> maybe because the server is executed on another process.

No.

NB `data` should not be static.